# Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect() in wamp

Tags: php, wamp

Hoping someone can find out where I am going wrong here, 'cause I'm going around and around and getting no where!
I've got a WAMP5 install which integrates PHP Version 5.2.4, Apache/2.2.4 (Win32) and MYSQL on a Win XP machine. All works fine, but I can't get LDAP support to work.

I've checked
extension_dir = "c:/wamp/php/ext/" and extension=php_ldap.dll in php.ini and checked the dll is actually in that folder.
I've copied libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll to the c:windows\system32 folder

With this code :

```
 $host = "192.168.56.25";
if (!$ldapconn = ldap_connect($host, 80)) {
   echo "Error! Could not connect to LDAP host $host\n";
}
```

I get this error : 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()...
I don't know where to start checking because I guess all conditions are achieved for my WAMP to take into consideration Ldap. Please help!
Thanks

Comment: have a look into the php error log. If php cann't load the dll it echos an error there

Comment: [19-Jan-2013 15:54:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[19-Jan-2013 15:54:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0

[19-Jan-2013 15:54:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
...

Comment: so the module is not there where it is expected

Comment: I guess this means the file c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_ldap.dll is not there ?

Comment: yep. you extension dir is c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/ not c:/wamp/php/ext/

Comment: I don'T understand your question. Are you sure, that the file c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_ldap.dll exists?

Comment: Exactly, the file exists here c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_ldap.dll

Comment: you computer says no. The question is why. The file is not there, apache is not allowed to read it. no idea

Answer (score 10):

You need to enable LDAP in your php.ini file. Uncomment this line:

```
extension=php_ldap.dll
```

Comment: What else do you think I should check?

Comment: The correct answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864306/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-ldap-connect . Go to second answer

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that the LDAP extension is installed on your server. There should be a package you need to install. I believe its:

`sudo apt-get install php5-ldap`

You may also want to check the [installation](http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php) guide. You might need to add another two DLLs `libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll`.

Comment: +1 because this helped me on Ubuntu.