# Fatal error: Call to undefined function: ldap_connect()

Tags: php, wamp

I get this error when using WAMP:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function: `ldap_connect()`

I have already edited the `php.ini` folder and enabled `php_ldap.dll`.

For some reason only some of the extensions show up in `phpinfo()` when I turn them on. I have restarted Apache and restarted my computer.

Comment: are the actual extensions available? like is php_ldap.dll in your extensions folder?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

If you are a Windows user, this is a common error when you use `XAMPP` since `LDAP` is not enabled by default.

You can follow this steps to make sure `LDAP` works in your `XAMPP`:

- `[Your Drive]:\xampp\php\php.ini`: In this file uncomment the following line:

  ```
   extension=php_ldap.dll
  ```
- Move the file: `libsasl.dll`, from  `[Your Drive]:\xampp\php` to  `[Your Drive]:\xampp\apache\bin` (Note: moving the file is needed only for XAMPP prior to version: `5.6.28`)
- Restart Apache.
- You can now use functions of the LDAP Module!

If you use Linux:

For php5:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-ldap
```

For php7:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-ldap
```

If you are using the latest version of PHP you can do

```
sudo apt-get install php-ldap
```

running the above command should do the trick.

if for any reason it doesn't work check your php.ini configuration to enable ldap, remove the semicolon before `extension=ldap` to uncomment, save and restart Apache

Comment: in my case for linux it was yum install php-ldap, package installed but still not able to login, maybe i need to restart ampps. :(

Comment: Copying the file is the key! Thanks a ton.

Comment: With current XAMPP (5.6.28), the file is already there and copying is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Chris I've updated the answer to handle the versions

Comment: The answer is correct for any installation of PHP, not only wamp/xampp (e.g PHP of IIS through web platform installer).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @AlonfromDataPlusResearch

Comment: Did anyone else notice this error outputs the username and password that the user supplied, in plain text to the error log file?

Comment: for XAMPP 3.2.X which has PHP 7.4 there we can simply enable extension=ldap

Answer (score 3):

Add path of your PHP to Windows System Path. The path should contain `php.exe`.

After adding the path open a new command prompt and make sure `php.exe` is in path by typing

```
C:\>php --help
```

Once you see proper help message from above, enable the `php_ldap.dll` extension in `php.ini`

Also copy `php_ldap.dll` from `php/ext` directory to `apache/bin` folder

Restart wamp and `phpinfo()` will now show ldap enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your contributions.
For my part, I needed to act on the 3 following points to make ldap_connect() work in PHP8.2.3 :

1. add php_ldap.dll to php.ini
2. copy libsasl.dll from PHP to APACHE
3. add the PHP path to the PATH environment variable
   then restart APACHE

Answer (score 0):

- [Your Drive]:\xampp\php\php.ini: In this file uncomment the following line:

  extension=php_ldap.dll
- Move the file: libsasl.dll, from [Your Drive]:\xampp\php to [Your Drive]:\xampp\apache\bin
  Restart Apache.
  You can now use functions of the LDAP Module!

Answer (score 0):

Open the XAMMP php.ini file (the default path is C:\xammp\php\php.ini) and change the code (;extension=ldap) to extension=php_ldap.dll and save. Restart XAMMP and save.

**php.ini**

```
; Notes for Windows environments :
;
; - Many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) or ext/ (PHP 5+)
;   extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5+).
;   Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
extension=php_ldap.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

My server is Windows Server 2016 with Apache 2.4, and I was having this error too. Move the file `libsasl.dll`, from `C:\php` to `C:\apache\bin` and  Restart Apache.