# Where can i find php.ini on cpanel

Tags: php, apache, active-directory, ldap, cpanel

I have a php file that authenticate with ldap, it was working fine on localhost but when i uploaded it to cpanel(softaculous), i got this error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()`, i know that i have to uncomment `extension=php_ldap.dll` in php.ini,but i can not find this file,where can i find the `php.ini` file in cpanel?Also i want to know from where i can restart the apache on cpanel?

```
// Active Directory server
$ldap_host = "CRAMSDCR01V.cloud4rain.local";

// connect to active directory
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function: ldap\_connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864306/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-ldap-connect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it under File Manager on cPanel

at the Top Right corner on your FIle Manager Page >> Klik Settings Button >> check the Show Hidden Files (dotfiles) option

you can add the the new file, if there's doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I found it thanks alot, it is a little bit different from the one i have on my PC,and i didn't find this line in `extension=php_ldap.dll`,do you have any idea why?

Comment: i have added the line `extension=php_ldap.dll`, i want to restart the apache,do you know from where?

Comment: you should ask to your web hosting provider to add php_ldp on their server.. and restart the apache service under root.

Answer (score 0):

**Go to root directory** of your website's cPanel. There are a number of directories and files in root directory. Among them there is php.ini file. Edit that. That's your required file.

If you are working in Ubuntu, just run this command

sudo service apache2 restart

Or if in xampp in windows : then go to its panel click on stop and then start again.