# Loading ldap driver onto MAMP on Mac OS X

Tags: php, ldap, mamp

Currently, I am getting an error

> fatal error: undefined function ldap_connect()

I am assuming this is because I do not have the library php_ldap.dll, but I am unsure how to even obtain it. Basically, I'm trying to get it so that ldap driver appears on the phpinfo page.

Please do not mark this question as duplicate: [Fatal error: Call to undefined function: ldap_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864306/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-ldap-connect). This solution works for Linux and Windows, but does not work on Mac OS.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you install PHP? Was is via brew

Comment: Probably? It was a couple months ago

Answer (score -1):

When you are on a Mac `php_ldap.dll` won't help you as that's a windows file.

If you are using MAMP you should have a look at the MAMP documentation to see how to enable other extensions. IIRC there is a possibility to enable extensions in the preferences somewhere but I might be wrong or that has changed since I looked the last time. If there is that possibility, you should be able to enable the LDAP extension there.