# php ldap extension on Virtualmin running CentOS7

Tags: php, linux, centos

I am trying to use the PHP LDAP function ldap_connect but I'm getting a fatal error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()
```

I have added `extension=php_ldap.dll` to `php.ini` and restarted Apache

I've also tried installing in the terminal which I get an unauthorised error

```
yum install php7-ldap
http://***:***@software.virtualmin.com/vm/6/centos/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized
Trying other mirror.
http://***:***@software.virtualmin.com/vm/6/universal/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized
Trying other mirror.
No package php5-ldap available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Call to undefined function: ldap\_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864306/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-ldap-connect)

Comment: @Philippe I did see that, and already try to install but it failed

Comment: Do you really want to still use PHP5? In any case, if that function is not available, check if the extension is loaded to get further info. See `extension_loaded()` and `function_exists()` documentation as well. Note that just because you added it to one php.ini, doesn't imply that every PHP interpreter even uses that file.

Comment: Hum, it's beyond my knowledge, but I advice you to : **remove the username:password** from your question. These information are certainly hard-coded in a configuration file and certainly incorrect.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt my mistake - i am using php 7, but still the same issue when trying to download the php7 version

Comment: Well, if that gives you the similar (probably not the same) output, then it's pretty clear: You need to fix your username/password or, maybe, that account is expired or blocked in any other way. None of this is a programming issue though, it's just one of installing software.

Comment: so, just fixed that. now if i run `yum install php-ldap` it returns this `Package php-ldap-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do` but the virtual server is set to use php7

Answer (score 1):

> I have added extension=php_ldap.dll to php.ini and restarted Apache

php extensions ending in .dll are for Windows systems not for Linux.

On linux you should add something like this to your php.ini file:

```
extension=ldap.so
```

Depending on how you run php on your server you need to restart either the webserver service (apache by default on CentOS) or if you run PHP using php-fpm then you'll have to restart php-fpm service