# Need PHP ldap extension on Docker Image with Apache2, PHP 5.6 and Oracle built on Debian Jessie

Tags: php, docker, ldap, debian-jessie

I have an PHP application that uses ldap functions, when I run it in Docker I get an error: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()". Docker image used for building the app is: https://github.com/thomasbisignani/docker-apache-php-oracle.
Is there a way to enable ldap extension without changing the Docker image used and what do I need to write extra in my Docker file to make it work. Right now my Docker file is simple only contains 4 lines:

```
FROM thomasbisignani/docker-apache-php-oracle
COPY  . /myapp
WORKDIR /var/www/html
CMD ["php","./index.php"]
```

Tryed adding this lines to Docker file:

```
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-dependencies-in-virtual-world openldap-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install ldap \
    && docker-php-ext-enable  ldap \
    && apk del .build-dependencies-in-virtual-world
```

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ldap-utils libldap2-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

and many more...

but I always get an error when building the app `docker build -t my-php-app .`:

```
ERROR [2/5] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ldap-utils ...
```

Comment: `apk` is for Alpine, not Debian, so the first attempt is certainly wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Call to undefined function: ldap\_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864306/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-ldap-connect)

Comment: no because the app works fine on my server and locally but not in docker

Comment: So in your `Dockerfile` you have to make the changes described in that post, changes that probably you have laready made on your server.

Comment: yes I understood your implication and did that and got following error when bulding app: '3.249 Err http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main php5-ldap amd64 5.6.17+dfsg-0+deb8u1
3.249   404  Not Found
3.254 E: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php5/php5-ldap_5.6.17+dfsg-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found'

Comment: This attempt (probably the most important!) is not described in your question.  However without a "Minimal, Reproducible Example" I cannot say more.

Comment: When I added "RUN apt-get install php5-ldap" in docker file I got the mentioned error.

Comment: That base image is 8 years old...

Comment: You can't `apt update` this image because it's so old and its repositories are no longer maintained. You _might_ be able to download the PHP 5.6 source tarball and compile just that module yourself, but you're better off updating to a more modern image.